# Who created the cover art from the newer Wild Cards Book I with Jetboy on it?

Tags: cover-art, wild-cards

Who created the cover art for the newer [Wild Cards I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_Cards_%28anthology%29) edition with [Jetboy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetboy#Jetboy) on it? (e.g. the one published in 2010.)

Is he or she responsible for the other covers?

[image: Wild Cards Book Cover]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cover images for the most recent reprint of the original series (now published as Wild Cards I, II and III) were designed by [Michael Komarck](http://www.komarckart.com/index.html).

[image: Wild Cards]

Although he's been responsible for the book covers, several of the individual stories have had had their own eBook illustrations commissioned by other artists including Hugo Award winning [John Picacio](http://www.johnpicacio.com/).

[image: John Picacio]

And [Mike S Miller](http://mikesmillerart.com/) for the omnibus fifth edition.

[image: George S Miller]

Answer (score 2):

Michael Komarck, found it in http://www.wildcardsonline.com/ news.